# C++ CListCtrl - GetItemData() returning wrong value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clistctrl, dword

I have a C++ application with an SQL backend, and have been storing the row id of any retrieved columns (an integer, primary key bigint in the database) with SetItemData() on list control rows as required. This is then retrieved with GetItemData() if that ID needs to be queried.

I am now getting a weird problem in that, in this one scenario, GetItemData() is returning a random 7-digit number instead of the stored ID. When I add the row I use the following code:

```
CListCtrl& lc = GetListCtrl();
for (int i = 0; i < vInsertItems.size(); i++) {
    int j = lc.InsertItem(i,i.strName);

    DWORD dwdRowID = (DWORD)cammms,nRowID;
    lc.SetItemData(j,dwdRowID);
}
```

To retrieve and check the value I can do the following (where I have determined that nCurrentlySelectedIndex is correct):

```
CListCtrl& lc = GetListCtrl();
int msgID = lc.GetItemData(nCurrentlySelectedIndex);
CString debugInt; debugInt.Format(_T("debugInt = %d"),msgID);
AfxMessageBox(debugInt);
```

What is bizarre, is that if I run the second batch of code directly after the first, it is all fine. But if I run it in a separate function, msgID becomes set to a set of random 7 digits, different every time.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: What are you doing between the first part of the code and the second part? What functions are you calling that are modifying the listctrl (InsertItem, SetItemData, ...)?

Comment: That's the thing - absolutely nothing. The first part of code is run by the function to populate the list control, and then that ends. The second part of the code runs unsuccessfully in an OnDblClick() method attached to the list control. The only thing that can be said to run between one and the other is the OnSelChange() method, which updates the nCurrentlySelectedIndex.

Comment: You should check nCurrentlySelectedIndex and for debug purpose maybe read the item's text to compare it to what you expect.

Comment: I am checking nCurrentlySelectedIndex. Prior to runnning the second part of code it is correct, and I can pull item's text and it reads as expected perfectly.